# Add custom property to entity data model

Tags: ado.net, wcf-data-services, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am new to using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model and WCF Data Service. I have created an entity model based on database and created a WCF Data service for this model. Service works great but i have one problem. I need to add custom property to existing model that will generate value based on owr business logic. I add new property with partial class but it does not show in WCF service results. Looks like WCF Data Service ignore this property. 
How do I add custom properties to entities that will be included in service results?

Thank you!

Comment: I have marked my property with DataMemberAttribute but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible as of now.
[Check here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/8115cf34-4527-4302-9123-0dce010629e0)